# HTML autocomplete

Tags: input, autocomplete, atom-editor

I'm a beginner in HTML which currently using Atom.

My question is: Is it good way to start coding with input set on autocomplete? Or should I type in every attribute manually.
For instance: Typing anchor tag I just need to type a and it will fill in automatic the rest.

as long as I know what is going on and understand what they mean of course.

Comment: If you understand what each element/attribute is doing, then there is no problem using the line break facility to load the general structure. But this is your coding journey, so ditch our opinions on how you should learn and just explore the language! Focus on actually creating things, as opposed to just following tutorials, as the process of getting stuck is where you'll learn the most :)

Comment: “Questions which are too broad, unclear, incomplete or primarily opinion-based may be closed by the community until they are improved”. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for details!